# Easily pause all audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I listen to music in my browser (be it Google Music, Spotify, Youtube, etc). Sometimes I need to quickly pause my music (e.g. when a colleague comes to my desk).

I do not have time to find the right browser tab and hit pause, so I currently lose my place in my music!

Is there a simple command I could run to pause all audio? I could assign it to a keyboard shortcut!

I've noticed that light-locker does exactly this! It pauses any audio when I lock my screen and carries on in the right place when I unlock. But I want to keep my screen unlocked when a colleague comes.

Any suggestions much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Is there no mute button on your keyboard ?

Comment: But the audio would carry on playing so I'd lose my place!

Comment: How about suspending the pulseaudio process? That seems to work (other than a 1 second loop repeated). Just need a nice command to do it!

Comment: Oh Yes thats true sorry I'm not sure if i can help you out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here's my best solution so far. Use this command to "pause" all audio:

```
/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/amixer -q -D pulse sset Master mute; /usr/bin/killall -q -STOP 'pulseaudio'"
```

And use this command to "unpause" audio:

```
/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/killall -q -CONT 'pulseaudio'; /usr/bin/amixer -q -D pulse sset Master unmute"
```

Use the Keyboard Settings to add these commands as application shortcuts (e.g. Super+Backspace to pause, Super+Enter to resume).

Answer (score 6):

By default the sound system used in Ubuntu is PulseAudio which consists of a server and clients. These are referred as `sinks` (for output devices) and `sources` (applications that play audio). PulseAudio supports suspending these sinks and sources which results in audio being paused/resumed.

To pause all audio:

```sh
pacmd suspend 1
```

To resume:

```sh
pacmd suspend 0
```

Answer (score 3):

There is now way to assign keyboard shortcuts to a whole range of audio/video actions in Ubuntu including pause, mute, volume up/down etc.

In Ubuntu 20.04 (and possibly previous versions) simply go into system settings. If using GNOME, select Keyboard Shortcuts and if using KDE it's "Shortcuts" and then "Global Shortcuts" under "Workspace"

**GNOME:**

1. Go into Settings
2. Click Keyboard Shortcuts
3. Select the "Sound and Media" category

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en

**KDE / Kubuntu:**

1. Go into System Settings
2. Click on "Shortcuts" under "Workspace"
3. Click on "Global Shortcuts"
4. Choose "Media Controller"

You will then be able to assign keyboard shortcuts to a variety of audio/video controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your keyboard settings and go to the Shortcuts tab and then select Sound and Media you should be able to replace the Audio mute button for "Volume mute" to your desired key combination.

Comment: OP asked for audio to NOT continue playing while muted, so that it can be resumed seamlessly when eventually unmuted.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is like me and wants to use the same shortcut for `pause` and `play`, then here is the command I am using

```
/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/pacmd info | /usr/bin/grep -q 'state: SUSPENDED' && /usr/bin/pacmd suspend 0 || /usr/bin/pacmd suspend 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `playerctl` tool addresses this (https://github.com/altdesktop/playerctl, Ubuntu package `playerctl`). It allows to pause (`playerctl pause`) arbitrary players. I do not know whether this includes all the players you mentioned but it does work with YouTube in Chromium, at least.